# Find the indefinite integral $\int x^2 \cos x dx$

Tags: calculus

Find the indefinite integral  $\int x^2 \cos x dx$. There's also a note that says "Solve by the simplest method—not all require integration by parts." But I don't see how else you would solve this without integration by parts.

Comment: When it says "not all require integration by parts", is it possible that this is one of the few problems in your list which does require it?

Answer (score 4):

Consider the integral
\begin{align}
I(a) = \int x^{2} \, \cos(ax) \, dx.
\end{align}
Now it can be seen that
\begin{align}
I(a) &= - \partial_{a}^{2} \int \cos(ax) \, dx \\
&= - \partial_{a}^{2} \left[ \frac{\sin(ax)}{a} \right] \\
&= \frac{(a^{2} x^{2}-2) \sin(a x)}{a^{3}} + \frac{2 x \cos(a x)}{a^{2}} + c_{1}
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

Note that 
$$
(x^2 \sin x)'= 2x\sin x + x^2 \cos x
$$

and
$$
(2x\cos x)'= 2\cos x - 2x\sin x \to (2x\cos x - 2\sin x)' = -2x\sin x 
$$

Then, 
$$
(x^2 \sin x + 2x\cos x - 2\sin x)' = x^{2}\cos x
$$

So, we have $\int x^{2}\cos x dx = x^2 \sin x + 2x\cos x - 2\sin x + C$.

Answer (score 1):

Here you must integration by parts:

$$ \int x^2 \cos x dx = \int x^2 d(\sin x) = x^2 \sin x - \int \sin x 2x dx = x^2 \sin x - 2 \int x \sin x dx = x^2 \sin x  + 2 \int x d( \cos x ) = x^2 \sin x + 2 x \cos x - 2 \int \cos x dx = x^2 \sin x + 2  x \cos x - 2 \sin x + K$$